# Logic Apps http trigger gives unresolvable hostname

Tags: azure-logic-apps

My Logic App starts with an http trigger.  I want my app to send an email if it fails due to unresolvable host name or a status code indicating failure.  What's the best way to do this?
I've put in a condition of the status code equal to 200, but this is not catching unresolvable host name.  Instead the app is hanging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now the logic app doesn't support set `Configure run after` directly following a trigger. So if you want to send an email after the logic app failed, you could use the `Alert` feature.

Here is the official tutorial: [Set up alerts for your logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-monitor-your-logic-apps#set-up-alerts-for-your-logic-app).